# OSX Lion Trash Won't Empty

Tags: sudo

I had a problem in Lion where empty trash would just sit there. In Terminal I ran the command sudo rm ~rf ~/.Trash/*  But an error message says that 'filename' is a directory. How can I get rid of this from the trash?

Answer (score 3):

Correct your command:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Use the minus sign "**-**" in front of "**rf**", since the options to the most commands are given with the minus sign "**-**", not with the tilde sign "**~**".
The tilde sign "**~**" represents your home directory, that's why **~/.Trash** is translated to the **.Trash** sub-directory in your home folder.

I intentionally skipped the "**sudo**" from your command, since you do not need root permissions to delete your own user's files. It is **dangerous** to use **sudo** if you do not know where it's needed.

Comment: Thanks and a big oops on my part using the ~ instead of - in front of rf. I've now successfully emptied the trash.